# Can I change which JSON file is loaded by sending a variable to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I would like to load the content of one of two JSON files, food1.json or food2.json. I am trying to do this from the html template:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init('food1')">
```

And then in the JS:

```
$scope.init = function (name) {
    $scope.name = name;
    $scope.category = name + ".json";
    $scope.foodlist = {};
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $scope.category,
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        {
            $scope.foodlist = data;
        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // something went wrong :(
    });
};
});
```

The category name is properly assembled: I get "I am food1" if I print `I am {{ category }}`. But no food items are printed. I think I am doing the JSON call wrong.

[Here's my Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DZy5H7UxGHQlnfcqFr26?p=preview)

Comment: use a console to look at errors...`$http undefined` error should have been a  clue to problem

Comment: Plunkr dumps a lot of errors to the console in Chrome, so I haven't been using it in these experiments, but you're right.

Comment: Plunkr had nothing to do with it... error is in your code

Comment: Yes, that is true. But looking for console errors is not as useful if the console is full of, e.g "
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://run.plnkr.co" from accessing a frame with origin "http://plnkr.co". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://run.plnkr.co/7OJ6MtOoaLlT549f/plunkerPreviewTarget.json
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://run.plnkr.co" from accessing a frame with origin "http://plnkr.co". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Comment: surely you don't develop in plunker

Comment: No, but I experiment in it. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not injected `$http` in the controller. Change you code as

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
```

instead of

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/CXlvEfJqh7B7J7QU6uGr?p=preview)